# Xamarin.Forms Search ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have this code in my ViewModel which searches a List of Items, the `OnSearchAsync(string searchQuery)` gets executed by a Command which is bound to `TextChanged` `Entry` Event

The `ObservableCollection<Items>` Collection is bound to `CollectionView`. There are 200 Items max in this Collection

I'm wondering if my Code could be improved or if I'm doing this wrong.

```
private async void OnSearchAsync(string searchQuery)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery) || searchQuery.Length < 2)
    {
        if (Items?.Count == _backupItems.Count)
        {
            return;
        }

        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(_backupItems);
        await RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var result = Search(searchQuery);
            if (result == null)
            {
                Items = null;
                return;
            }

            var results = result.ToList();
            if (results.Count == 0)
            {
                Items = null;
                return;
            }

            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(results);
            await RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Items));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(this, ex);
        }
}

   public IEnumerable<Item> Search(string text)
   {
        try
        {
            return _backupItems.Where(x => x.Property1.Text.CaseContains(text) ||
                                        x.Property2.Text.CaseContains(text) ||
                                        x.Property3.Text.CaseContains(text) ||
                                        x.Property4.Text.CaseContains(text));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(this, ex);
        }
        return null;
 }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are re-instantiating your observable collection instead of simply clearing it and adding new items to it? I was also wondering about the async RaisePropertyChanged method